# How to calculate error for polynomial fitting (in slope and intercept)

Tags: python, numpy, statistics, scipy

Hi I want to calculate errors in slope and intercept which are calculated by scipy.polyfit function. I have (+/-) uncertainty for ydata so how can I include it for calculating uncertainty into slope and intercept? My code is,

```
from scipy import polyfit
import pylab as plt
from numpy import *

data = loadtxt("data.txt")
xdata,ydata = data[:,0],data[:,1]


x_d,y_d = log10(xdata),log10(ydata)
polycoef = polyfit(x_d, y_d, 1)
yfit = 10**( polycoef[0]*x_d+polycoef[1] )


plt.subplot(111)
plt.loglog(xdata,ydata,'.k',xdata,yfit,'-r')
plt.show()
```

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [`scipy.optimize.curve_fit`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html) instead of `polyfit`. It has a parameter `sigma` for errors of ydata. If you have your error for every y value in a sequence `yerror` (so that `yerror` has the same length as your `y_d` sequence) you can do:

```
polycoef, _ = scipy.optimize.curve_fit(lambda x, a, b: a*x+b, x_d, y_d, sigma=yerror)
```

For an alternative see the paragraph *Fitting a power-law to data with errors* in the [Scipy Cookbook](http://www.scipy.org/Cookbook/FittingData).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes I have seen that power law function but how can I combine my +/- error together with ydata? For example my ydata looks like, Y = 5 (+0.1, -0.4), 4.7 (+0.7,-0.4),..etc.

Comment: @viralparekh You have an asymmetric deviation of your values? Never seen that before :) Could you elaborate a little on why the positive deviation is different from the negative.

Comment: It shows confidence region. so 1st Y value is between (5.09 and 4.59) and so on. It just showing +ve(high) and -ve(low) error.