# How to calculate errors on slopes of linear fits when y-errors are asymmetric

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have a data set with values that can be plotted as x-values against y-values.
Data on the y-axis have asymmetric errors, i.e.,

[image: y_i=10^{+2}_{-1.5}]

I want to fit these data with a linear function.
I can do this fit in a number of way in python, but all of them have the same problem, that is, how to get the errors of the fit parameters too.

Very related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12706528/how-to-calculate-error-for-polynomial-fitting-in-slope-and-intercept), but impossible (or at least, not straightforward) to use [scipy.optimize.curve_fit](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html) since my data have asymmetric errors on the ordinate (y-axis) in order to get the slope error as well.

Then, how can I calculate errors on slopes of linear fits when y-error bars are asymmetric?

Is there any python function for this?

Comment: Please, the question seems to me clear and very specific. Could you tell me what is wrong here?

Comment: Just FYI, you can embed LaTeX using a site like [this one](http://latex.codecogs.com/png.latex?c=\sqrt{a^2%2bb^2}).

Answer (score 0):

There's a paper by Barlow+04 https://arxiv.org/abs/physics/0406120 on finding the mean of variables with asymmetric error bars. You could perhaps use these techniques.

The brute force route that I take is to draw many realisations of the variable from a split-normal distribution (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split_normal_distribution) and store the best-fitting polynomial parameters for them. I then compute the median and 1-sigma upper/lower error bars (from the 84th and 16th percentile from the median, respectively) for each polynomial parameter.

The code below, in Python 2.7.9, does this. There's a function for computing a split-normal value, the errors from the percentiles and fitting a polynomial.

Hope this helps.

```
#! /bin/python

from random import choice, gauss
from numpy import polyfit

def split_normal(mus, sigmas_u68, sigmas_l68):
    """
    RET: A split-normal value.
    """

    split_normal = []

    for mu, sigma_u68, sigma_l68 in zip(mus, sigmas_u68, sigmas_l68):

        sigma = choice([sigma_u68, -sigma_l68])
        g = abs(gauss(0.0, 1.0)) * sigma + mu
        split_normal.append(g)

    return split_normal

def errors_84_16(x):
    """
    RET: 1-sigma upper/lower error bars from the 84/16th percentile
         from the median.
    """

    n = len(x)

    index_med = n / 2 # median.
    index_84 = int(round(n * 0.84135)) # 84th percentile from median.
    index_16 = int(round(n * 0.15865))

    x_sorted = sorted(x)
    x_med = x_sorted[index_med]
    x_u68 = x_sorted[index_84] - x_med # 1-sigma upper error.
    x_l68 = x_med - x_sorted[index_16] # 1-sigma lower error.

    return x_med, x_u68, x_l68

def assymetric_polyfit(x, y, y_u68, y_l68, n_mc=500):
    """
    DES: Solves y = a + b * x for assymentric y error bars.
    RET: [a, a_u68, a_l68, b, b_u68, b_l68].
    """

    a_mc = []
    b_mc = []

    for i in xrange(0, n_mc):
        y_mc = split_normal(y, y_u68, y_l68)
        pars = polyfit(x, y_mc, 2)
        a_mc.append(pars[2])
        b_mc.append(pars[1])


    a, a_u68, a_l68 = errors_84_16(a_mc)
    b, b_u68, b_l68 = errors_84_16(b_mc)

    return a, a_u68, a_l68, b, b_u68, b_l68

def example():
    """
    """

    x = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0]
    y = [5.0, 8.0, 11.0, 14.0, 17.0] # 2 + 3x
    y_u68 = [0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5]
    y_l68 = [1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5]

    pars = assymetric_polyfit(x, y, y_u68, y_l68)
    print(pars)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    example()
```